# Getting Access Token for current user from bot sdk deployed in Azure

Tags: azure, botframework

I need to get access token for the current user in bot solution.
As it is like console application we cannot use httpcontext.

We have seen few options which suggest to give sign in option in bot window. But our customer dont want to sign in bot window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue using ADAL.JS.
Adal helps to get both access token and user details using single sing in